# Is there a way to acces the clicked value of a gcheckboxgroup (gwidgets2RGtk2)

Tags: r, user-interface, event-handling, gwidgets, rgtk2

I want to build a GUI where it is possible to click on a variable to take a look at at some data, and then decide via checkbox if you want to use it or not.

Using *use.table = T* i can make the different values of the checkboxgroup clickable/markable but i fail to receive the index/row/value of the row i clicked.

I've tried different handler, but i can only grab the values of the checkboxes, not the clicked row.

```
w <- gwindow("win", visible = T)
g <-
  gcheckboxgroup(
    c("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"),
    use.table = T,
    container = w,
    handler = function(h, ...)
      print("checkbox changed")
  )
```

[I want to get the index of the blue marked space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeJY6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for `svalue`, as in `svalue(g)` or `svalue(g, index=TRUE)`.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I am not looking for the svalue, since it returns me the values of the checkboxes. I am looking for a way to get the clicked row in the table which contains the checkboxes. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: `svalue(..., index=TRUE)`?